# CPU damage after bent pins on motherboard

Tags: cpu, motherboard, repair

I managed to bend the pins on the CPU socket on my Asus Z170-DELUXE (socket 1151).

The result in motherboard not starting and a high pitched (sine/whine) sound from the motherboard.

Now, I have heard you can try to bend the pins back in place and I have read many tips on how to do so. There are two things I am worried about here.

If I manage to bend the pins back in place, is there a possibility that the CPU might take damage if the pins are not 100% in place?

Also, is there any way to check the CPU fully to ensure that the CPU works completely?

[image]

**UPDATE**: I managed to bend the pins back (an almost perfect position). However the motherboard did not work, probably damaged already. The CPU on the other han worked perfectly!

Comment: Yes; it's possible;

Comment: Since LGA 1151 processors does north have any pins, how can the CPU be damaged by this? Any sources/references?

Comment: What?  You asked if it was possible, my answer to your question, yes you could damage the CPU.  Your comment is confusing

Comment: If this is your answer why did you not post it as an answer then? I asked you how it is possible since you replied with only a comment. No reason to down vote simply because I asked if you had any references for your claim.

Comment: voting is annymous

Comment: Yes voting is anonymous. Did you vote down my question?

Comment: While you _can_ bend back the pins, I would highly recommended that you don't.  Try and send the board back if it is still under warrantee.  The days lost by sending it back outweigh the possibility of screwing it up even more trying to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no telling without trying if damage may occur after the pins are bent back into place.  It will be a precarious procedure, and I would let a professional handle it if you could.

I would say if you manage to bend them back and the computer boots up, you should be alright.

For testing the CPU, you can try the [Intel Processor Diagnostic Tool](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/19792/Intel-Processor-Diagnostic-Tool).